# Razor Pages: Does OnGet Handler "accept" a request body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

When fetching a razor page, is it possible to pass a Request-Body to it? When the OnGet handler is called, `this.Request.Body` or `this.HttpContext.Request.Body` seem to be empty:
[image: OnGet Body empty]

This doesn't seem to be the case for OnPost handler (duh):
[image]

In my opinion using Query-Parameters instead of a Request-Body is more suitable for a GET-Request, however there is the complaint that the URL would be too long when calling the page.

Question is, can I read the Request-Body in the OnGet handler somehow? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I read the Request-Body in the OnGet handler somehow

No,You can send a request body with Get request,bu the requst body will be ignored.So if you want to send a request body,you can use Post or Put request.

Comment: Thank you! I looked up the documentation but wasn't able to find anything related. Can you perhaps point me somewhere? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body